# is AMD processors compatible with intel mpi?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I setup Intel mpi for parallel processing between 2 node with AMD opteron processor 2378 2.4GHZ and 16 GB memory. but this problem occur when i launch ansys. before it i launched successfully between to node with Intel processors and not have a problem with it.how can i solve this? 
[image: 1]

Comment: S.O does not deal with such questions AFAIK. You may be fortunate if you find a person answering this hardware related question in a programming related Q & A based community. I'm neither voting this down. You can try some other communities for solutions.

Comment: Yes, Intel MPI will run fine on AMD processors. But we cannot help you, because you do not describe your problem. Eventually it sounds like a off-topic non-programming question like Venky mentioned.

Comment: "run fine" doesn't sound convincing. If you push data across processors+servers, proof of consistence is paramount. Do you work for AMD/Intel and can add some facts to this statement?